# Pourquoi est-ce que le décompte des années se fait avec des cardinaux et non des ordinaux ?

Tags: nombres, dates, adjectifs

Dans les différents calendriers existant ou ayant existé (julien, grégorien, grégorien proleptique, républicain, révolutionnaire soviétique, hégirien…), l’usage francophone voudrait qu’on les désigne par un cardinal (An I, an 1, an 2000, an 0) et jamais par un ordinal (An 1er, an 2000ème, an 0ème).

Pourquoi en est-il ainsi ? Et surtout, existe-t-il là-dessus une publication de l’Académie, de l’OQLF, ou même d’un quelconque organisme ou d’un grammairien recommandant ou seulement commentant cet usage ?

Comment: Pas pour répondre à votre question intéressante, mais je crois que j’ai vu « **[L’an premier](https://books.google.com/books?id=RzNYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA822&lpg=PA822&dq=%22l%27an+premier%22+calendrier+revolutionnaire+%22l%27an+II%22&source=bl&ots=bfpbq4bvsx&sig=3v3S2UkCJUUabvK0Ygw7a7ge5xE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMIiJ3kwqPZyAIVDSuICh2R3AvK#v=onepage&q=%22l%27an%20premier%22%20%22l%27an%20II%22&f=false)** [de la république] » pour servir comme l'exception qui confirme la règle dont vous parlez.

Comment: Pas pour répondre à votre question, mais simplement pour la culture générale : sachez que l'an zéro n'existe pas dans le calendrier grégorien. On passe du 31 décembre de l'an 1 avant Jésus-Christ au 1er janvier de l'an 1 après Jésus Christ. (Un casse-tête supplémentaire pour les informaticiens et les historiens dans les problèmes de datations) ;-)

Comment: Je n’ai pas dis le contraire dans mon message, j’ai parlé de l’année 0 du calendrier grégorien groleptique et non du grégorien simple (qui comme vous le dîtes ne compte pas de nullième année).

Answer (score 2):

L'Académie française a émis un commentaire sur son site : [Questions de langue : an, année](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#10_strong-em-an-anne-em-strong)

Il s'agit de numérotation, ce qui correspond bien à l'usage d'un cardinal : il en va de même avec un dossard, avec la page d'un livre ou un numéro de billet, même s'il existe le plus souvent un ordre (et donc un ordinal) sous-jacent...

On peut néanmoins s'interroger sur le fait que les siècles ne sont employés, eux, qu'avec un ordinal. Sans doute faut-il attendre encore un peu pour qu'on parle du "siècle 133", voire du millénaire 7...

Answer (score 1):

Le nombre désignant une période annuelle à un double sens, il sert à :

- ***classer***, il découpe le temps en années consécutives permettant le calcul de période, de durée et donc de dire l'avant et l'après, il donne l'ordre des événements connus, et se sert donc de références ordinales.

L'usage se sert de l'*année*, temps de révolution de la terre autour du Soleil<sup>1</sup>, c'est une *durée* anonyme, que l'on reconnaît par sa place dans le classement calendaire.

> Cette réponse est donnée *durant* la quinzième année du troisième millénaire de l'ère chrétienne.
>
> Il est *dans sa* vingtième année (et donc a été précédé de dix neufs autres années).

On utilise donc la notion de durée pour classer et ordonner ces périodes, et l'usage emploie *année*, en référence au Temps astronomique, universel ; c'est une perception de l'Univers.

- ***nommer***, une *année* est appelée *an* quand elle porte une identité particulière, lorsqu'elle est cardinale.

Il y a une lecture individuelle, une sorte de personnification<sup>2</sup>, un nom est donné à une période de 365 jours :

> L'an 1789 a vu, entre autres événements, la Révolution française... jusqu'au 31 décembre où le récit s'arrête.

... et de ce fait il n'est pas une 1789<sup>e</sup> année, mais un an inscrit dans un calendrier unique et bien précis.

On utilise le nombre comme une étiquette pour qualifier cette période, et l'usage emploie alors *an*, qui a une durée voisine de celle de l'année astronomique, mais qui est défini par un calendrier en référence au Temps historique, culturel, c'est un jalon posé par l'humain.

---

<sup>1 - *Références du petit Robert*.

2 -  Comme si la mémoire pouvait l'interroger : "Que vous est-il arrivé, durant votre mandature, [Monsieur] l'An 1000 ?" ; l'an 1000 n'est pas la 1001ème  année après l'année de référence (d'ailleurs historiquement incertaine), mais le nombre donné précédé de *an* devient unique, il représente une référence de l'Histoire, une collections de faits à mettre en perspective.</sup>

Comment: Les années ne sont pas toujours ordinales: « Après trois années de guerre... » est l'équivalent de « Après trois ans de guerre... ».

Comment: @jliagre: là c'est un peu différent quand même, tu introduis une quantité plutôt qu'un identifiant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Est-ce que ma correction apporte plus de précision ?

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, la période *an* recouvre approximativement la période *année* et peut être substituée. J'ai complété ma réponse, ce et je perçois une nuance (peut-être très subjective) : trois années exprime 3x365j (avec "au début de.. , au milieu de .., en fin de..") ; trois ans donne trois calendriers consécutifs (avec des dates de références significatives).